# Signalr Not working after phone on sleep mode for long time in IOS and Andriod by PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, ios, signalr, phonegap

I am doing PhoneGap App for IOS and Android, in my app i have a chat system, and i am facing issue if my phone enters in sleep mode for long time (more then 30 minutes) then signalr is not working, Please help!

Comment: Check whether the device is connected when the application leaves the background state and connect if not.

Comment: can i have to connect on resume